# How to report algorithm running time?

Tags: tensorflow, runtime, tensorboard

I am running a variational auto-encoder in TensorFlow, which could take a long time. **Thus I want to report the time the algorithm has been running for as a scalar on TensorBoard**.

One dirty way is to hard-code the start time of the compilation into a global variable, or pass it as an argument to the model function and compute the difference with current time.

Does Tensorflow have a native way to do it?

Comment: Have you had a look at [TensorFlow Profiler and Advisor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md)?

Comment: No, that looks quite useful, I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [tf.train.ProfilerHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ProfilerHook). Comes with release 1.14.

**Example usage:**

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(...)
hooks = [tf.train.ProfilerHook(output_dir=model_dir, save_secs=600, show_memory=False)]
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=hooks)
```

Executing the hook will generate files `timeline-xx.json` in `output_dir`.

Then open `chrome://tracing/` in chrome browser and load the file. You will get a time usage timeline like below.
[image]

Comment: This solution works, although the JSON file is the same after 2,000 ms. I will try the suggestion by @jdehesa to see if it's different and if I can have results inside TensorBoard.